# Declare integer throughout program VB

Tags: vb.net, global-variables

So I am a c# programmer who needs to make a program in VB for school. So heres my issue, I need to declare an integer that can be referenced throughout the program so I can make a counter. I know in C# I am able to do :

private int count = 0;

But I am not sure how to do this in VB.

Thanks

Comment: The same line in VB would be `Dim count as Integer = 0` or `Private count as Integer = 0` at the class level.  See [Variable Declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ke6sh835.aspx).

Comment: Making a variable private is the opposite of making it available throughout the program.

Answer (score 0):

Add a module to your project and declare your global variables over there, so that you can access it from any of your form.